# "fetch_assoc" values changing with if-statement, PHP?

Tags: php, sql

I'm having a very bizzare situation and I can't figure out what's going on.

I have the following code:

```
$conn->query("UPDATE teachers SET active=1 WHERE id=".$next_teacher_id);

$list_of_arr=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE id>=".$next_teacher_id);
$k = $list_of_arr->fetch_assoc();
    $choice_array=unserialize($k['arr']);
    foreach ($choice_array as $j) {
        $matched_query=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE taken_by='' AND name LIKE '%".$j."%'");
        $matched_row=$matched_query->fetch_assoc();
        if (isset($matched_row['id'])) {
            $qu="UPDATE students SET taken_by='".$k['name']."' WHERE id=".$matched_row['id'];
            echo($qu);
            $conn->query($qu);
            break;
        }
    $k=$list_of_arr->fetch_assoc();

}
```

This will echo `UPDATE students SET taken_by='' WHERE id=19`

However, if I instead change the line (without changing anything else):

```
if (isset($matched_row['id']))
```

To:

```
if (isset($k['name']))
```

I now get an echo of:

```
UPDATE students SET taken_by='John Smith' WHERE id=
```

As a control experiment, if I say:

```
if(true)
```

I get as output:

```
UPDATE students SET taken_by='John Smith' WHERE id=
```

So the two different ways I do it actually switch my output, and I can't get both to be in the query variable. What exactly is going on here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Write your where conditions in this format `WHERE id='".$next_teacher_id."'`

Comment: That just gives me this: `UPDATE students SET taken_by='John Smith' WHERE id=''` as output. Somehow it seems that one of values is becoming null. But I don't see how the two variables are affecting each other.

Comment: but you are writing your query in wrong syntax.

Comment: @SwetaParmar but I tried correcting it as you explained and it echoed `UPDATE students SET taken_by='John Smith' WHERE id=''`, and also as a sidenote, `id` in my table is an INT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually finally did figure out a solution. Essentially because it was a `foreach` loop and I accidentally misplaced my bracket so the `fetch_assoc()`, was *inside* the `foreach` loop when it should've been outside. The `if-statement` wasn't changing any variable, it was that the `foreach` loop was iterating and only echoed a statement when the condition was true, hence why changing the statement changed the output. Moving the `fetch_assoc()` line below the bracket fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this:

```
$conn->query("UPDATE teachers SET active=1 WHERE id='".$next_teacher_id."');

$list_of_arr=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE id>='".$next_teacher_id."');
$k = $list_of_arr->fetch_assoc();
    $choice_array=unserialize($k['arr']);
    foreach ($choice_array as $j) {
        $matched_query=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE taken_by='' AND name LIKE '%".$j."%'");
        $matched_row=$matched_query->fetch_assoc();
        if (isset($matched_row['id'])) {
            $qu="UPDATE students SET taken_by='".$k['name']."' WHERE id='".$matched_row['id']."'";
            echo $qu;
            $conn->query($qu);
            break;
        }
    $k=$list_of_arr->fetch_assoc();

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Sweta. I realized this is actually not the solution, even though I appreciate that you helped me make the syntax correct.